# Chernoff Bounds (upper tail)

Tags: algorithms, probabilistic-algorithms, chernoff-bounds

For the proof of Chernoff Bounds (upper tail) we suppose δ<2e−1 . 
Like in this paper ([see this link ]) [1](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jfc/cs174/lecs/lec10/lec10.pdf). Can you tell me why ?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to make it self-contained, so it is understandable without having to click on the link, and so it will make sense even if the link stops working?

Comment: It simplifies the calculations somewhat. Actually the lecture notes clearly state that you don’t have to assume it.